# English letters are more bold than non-English in code in comments

Tags: bug, comments, ios-app, inline-code

Looks like the English letters are more bold than non-English in [comment section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/973030) for inline code formatting in the Stack Exchange iOS app:

> [image: iOS]

Web version shows them with same boldness:

> [image: Web]

- App Version: 1.7.0.1
- Device: iPad Pro 10.5-Inch (Wi-Fi) (iPad7,3)
- OS Version: Version 10.3.3 (Build 14G60)