# Fix links to moved sandbox posts and comments

Tags: feature-request, broken-link, sandbox

Today I noticed that all answers from [Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/339911) were moved to archive again.

I don’t know the actual reason why they were moved, but some of my bug reports have links to sandbox’s posts/comments, and now such links are broken.

Is it possible to automatically fix such links as it was made while migrating from http to https or simply redirect to archived item?

Comment: This came up before, with the [response](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6031923#6031923)  "why wouldn't you put your example as an answer on the bug report itself?"

Comment: is this [one of the lost posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296077/sandbox-archive/299247#299247)? thanks to @Sha : https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6391968#6391968 and this is the other one: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296077/sandbox-archive/286872#286872 you have also one deleted post there.

Comment: @rene all of them can be found via [search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=User%3A339911+wiki%3A1), but it’s not obvious if link from the original bug report is broken.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Posts in the sandbox are subject to delete or archiving at any time...

...you don't usually build sand castles for posterity, eh?

Buuuut, you can keep these links working if you want: just use short URLs. Like, /q/[id] or /a/[id] - those will continue working even if the answer is later moved.

Comment: Looks like the link to comment is not working if I use /a/[id] format.

Comment: @alexolut comments really should not be used in bug reports, they are temporary to begin with, even without sandbox.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd but, but... but my [report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299335/339911) is about comment :)

Comment: @alexolut oh. Well, screenshot should be enough.

Comment: @alexolut that said, URL like `https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/[id]` might still work, e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/981370

Comment: @alex... Just post comments on your actual bug report. Even if the sandbox wasn't getting archived, clicking through is super annoying.

Comment: You're right. I just made an experiment in the sandbox first, and then I created a bug-report with links.

Comment: *build sand castles for **posterity*** or ***prosperity***?